# How a process can refer to objects that are not in its address space (for example, a file or another process)?

Tags: reference, process, kernel

I have the homework question:

```
Explain how a process can refer to objects that are not in its 
address space (for example, a file or another process)?
```

I know that each process is created with an address space that defines access to every memory mapped resource in that process [(got that from this book)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201773449). I think that the second part to this question does not make sense. How can a process reference an object of another process? Isn't the OS suppose to restrict that? maybe I am not understanding the question correctly. Anyways if I understood the question correctly the only way that will be possible is by using the kernel I believe.

Comment: The OS can choose to set up 1:N mappings of pages instead of the usual 1:1 for specific system calls (e.g. mmap, shm etc.). This is on a per-page basis so the usual rules aren't "violated", specific exceptions are granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking it in a general sense, then its a no. Operating systems do not allow one process to access another process's virtual address space under the normal circumstances.
However there are ways in which you can create a controlled environment where such a thing can be done using various techniques.

A perfect example is the debugger. It uses process tracing mechanism (like reading from /proc filesystem or using the ptrace() system calls) to gain access to read and write from another address space.

There is also a shared memory concept, where a particular piece of memory is explicitly shared between two processes and can be controlled via a shared memory object.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach as a debugger to the application.  Or if using Windows, you can use [windows hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces)

Answer (score 0):

I have researched and I have the answer to the file part of the question.

> first of an **address space** is the collection of addresses that a
>   thread can reference. Normally these addresses reference to an
>   executable in memory. Some operating systems allow a programmer to
>   read and write the contents of a file using addresses from the process
>   **address space**. This is accomplished by opening the file, then binding each byte in the file to an address in the address space.

The second part of the question this is what I will answer:

> Most operating systems will not allow reading addresses from another
>   process. This will imply a huge security risk. I have not heard of any
>   operating system that enables you to read data from a thread that is
>   not owned by the current process. So in short I believe this will not
>   be possible.